# Meaning of curly braces after the "is" operator

Tags: c#, operator-keyword, curly-braces, c#-8.0

I found in some C# source code the following line:

```
if(!(context.Compilation.GetTypeByMetadataName("Xunit.FactAttribute")
         is { } factAttribute))
```

and here is another one:

```
if(!(diagnostic.Location.SourceTree is { } tree))
```

What is the meaning of the curly braces (`{ }`) after the `is` operator?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a new pattern matching feature which was introduced in C# 8.0 and is called [property pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/). In this particular case it is used to check that object is not null, example from the linked article:

```
static string Display(object o) => o switch
{
    Point { X: 0, Y: 0 }         p => "origin",
    Point { X: var x, Y: var y } p => $"({x}, {y})",
    {}                           => o.ToString(),
    null                         => "null"
};
```

Comment: Is it works the same as using `not null` pattern? I know the empty braces allow us to create an alias for this pattern but I'm not sure in the case if we don't need the alias.

Comment: @anuith yes, it does. If you don't need alias you should be able to use both interchangeably.

Comment: @anuith The curly bracket pattern is required when you want to assign the checked value directly to a newly declared variable such as in `if (iterator.Read() is {} item)`.