# What does 'is { }' syntax mean in c#?

Tags: c#

In the last couple of weeks I started encountering this new syntax in C#:

```
if (someObj is { })  
{    
    do some stuff 
}
```

so it returns bool. It seems like JavaScript a little bit. But what exactly does this check do? Is it identical to this?

```
if (someObj == null)
{
    do some stuff
}
```

I know that new versions of C# contain a lot of syntactic sugar. Is this part of that? Does it have some name or something? E.g., I know that `?:` is called the ternary operator and `?.` is called the Elvis operator. But what is `is { }`? Is it even an operator?

And yes, I've tried to search online before asking here, but it seems that Google refuses to find anything useful concerning the `is { }` syntax, because of the braces in the request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - meaning of curly braces after the "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139886/c-sharp-meaning-of-curly-braces-after-the-is-operator) This is a [property pattern](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0)

Comment: Yes, it's really helpful. Now, I know that it's called property pattern, so I can google it further, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the more general sense, this is member-based pattern matching - for example:

```cs
if (foo is { Id: 42, Name: "abc"})
{

}
```

tests whether `foo` has `Id` 42 and `Name` "abc". In this case, you are testing zero properties, so it *effectively* becomes the same as `is object` (i.e. a not `null` test, or a no-op `true` for non-nullable value-types).

To compare against what you have in the question (`if (someObj == null)`) - it is the *opposite* of that, noting that it will also not use an overloaded `==` operator for the `null` test (which `== null` *will*).

Comment: can you share link to docs for this ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad "recursive pattern matching": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns