# What is and how does { }; works in c#?

Tags: c#

While checking some repo I found out [this](https://github.com/SamProf/MatBlazor/blob/master/src/MatBlazor.DevUtils/DemoContentGenerator.cs#L35) and it broke my mind.

Example:

```
 var config = Config.GetConfig();
 var gen = new MatDocumenationGenerator(typeof(BaseMatDomComponent).Assembly,
            Path.Combine(config.Path, "MatBlazor.Demo", "Doc"));
 {
 }
 ;
 gen.Generate();
```

How it's possible to have `{ };` inside a method? Why it isn't a compile error?

I'm not sure but maybe it's some feature of the language? If yes, what does this do or is used for? How it works?

I tried to search what is this, but I don't even know how to call this, so, is there a name for this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# - meaning of curly braces after the "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139886/c-sharp-meaning-of-curly-braces-after-the-is-operator) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212715/what-does-is-syntax-mean-in-c), or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns)

Comment: By itself, `{ };` is an empty block followed by an empty statement. So it has no effect.

Comment: Other commenters, the example has nothing to do with pattern matching nor object initialization.

Comment: @mason - no its not... there is a semicolon on the line before it, therefore it is not linked to the new statement, and just defines an empty block. Maybe it was intended as that and the semi colon was a mistake, but its defos not working like that

Comment: I would agree that it is simply an empty block followed by an empty statement, but that explicitly setting every part on a new line makes me somewhat suspicious. Maybe worth to do a blame and ask the original author?

Comment: Can anyone reference some doc about this? Because now I'm confused. Gold badge in C# guy say it's object initializer, others say it's scope...

Comment: @Vencovsky Most of us are confused. We can figure out, what this is and that it does nothing, really. Probably the optimizer will throw it out completely. What's confusing is why it _is_ there in the first place...

Comment: It could just be a typo. That the intention was to use an object initializer, but added a `;` by reflex.

Comment: Voting to reopen because the duplicate question does not have the `;` following the block, nor does it explain how empty blocks can appear.

Comment: I have the suspicion this has been introduced accidentally by merging in a pull request ...

Comment: @Vencovsky I originally said it was an object initializer, I missed the semicolon at the end of the line. Sorry for any confusion I might have caused. It's just a nested code block that does nothing in this case. I think it was *meant* to be an object initializer by the writer of the code, since it always follows a constructor, but in actual effect it's just an empty code block. See the duplicate that Tom marked this as.

Comment: @JoeSewell Since that semicolon makes it part of a different line, it's irrelevant. The duplicate is perfectly suitable.

Comment: a line of a thousand semicolons does not generate a warning either. related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2374612/1132334

Comment: according to git blame, it was [added in one go](https://github.com/SamProf/MatBlazor/commit/1ec107fd0cd044485b4d69876f605711d191a6ca#diff-ed7c9da2ff9c3e4feecbe249679d36f1R26), does not look like a merge artifact. it is likely a harmless mistake. if it was done on purpose, only [the author](https://www.samprof.com/) can answer this.

Answer (score 4):

It's valid code that does nothing, and is redundant.  It's almost certainly a mistake and could be removed without affecting the program.  The compiler doesn't warn about everything that's redundant, although I agree it possibly could and should in this case.

Comment: It's easy to understand that the code does nothing, but how does it work? Could you explain that please? And by "how does it work" I mean, it is really going on with `{ };`. Why it's possible?

Comment: "{}" is a legal statement and ";" is another legal statement. Both do nothing and will probably just be optimized away and not even appear in IL Code (how would they? As NOPs at best).

Comment: @Vencovsky because C# permits a block (`{...}`) in that context and empty blocks are permitted. The `;` does not associate with the block

Comment: @Fildor saying `"{}" is a legal statement and ";" is another legal statement` is like saying `X works because it works, Y works because it works`. I understand what you say about that, but still, no explanation

Comment: I think the true explanation is hidden in the "duplicate" post. `{}` works because it's a "inner" scope. And you can open as many scopes you want. The same with `;` you can have as many `;` you want, making some crazy think like `{}{}{}{;;;;}{};;;;{}` a valid c# code

Comment: Yes, I suppose the 'reason' is ; works on its own because we can have an empty line that does nothing, and { } works on its own because we can have an empty scope block that does nothing.  There's no point in these things though, so the compiler could warn in both cases.

Comment: @Fildor I just explained, please read my comment above. Rich N also did it

Comment: @Vencovsky Saying "X works because it works" is often how you'll use to describe code compiling. We see questions like yours all the time, saying "why does this work" and the answer is "The people writing the compiler didn't take the time to make it not work, because it wasn't necessary to do so". In other words, it works because it works.

Comment: @Vencovsky Yep, just did. I think that's it, basically. There's really nothing more to it. And as I commented on the question, my suspicion is that it was introduced by accident while merging in a pull request.

Comment: ^^ That being said, the authors may appreciate a hint, so they can clean it up.

Comment: ok I can prepare a PR but what do we tell him? your intellisense hiccup from a decade ago has enthralled distinguished random strangers on the internet, pondering a secret meaning behind an accidential NOP? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `{...}` in almost every language. Java, C++, C#... It simply opens a [Scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/) which defines the lifetime of variables that live on the Stack (not on the heap)

Example:

```
void someFunction () { 
    // some code here
    {
        var a = 5;
    }

    // 'a' does not exist anymore after the '}'

}
```

Comment: In JavaScript the rules are different

Comment: Still answers the question 'How it's possible to have { }; inside a method?'

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad, I removed "js" because it's in fact a bit different.

Comment: Wrong. This is not a scope definition in this case.

Comment: @TomTom it defines a scope.

Comment: @TomTom It most certainly *does* define a scope. The variable `a` only exists inside the brackets defining the block.