# What's the difference between is object and is {} in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

So, I think in the current C# version which is C# 8. There are a few ways to check the reference types are not `null`. I am confused by these two below:

1. `o is object`
2. `o is {}`

What's the main difference between them, I cannot find much info for them.

Can someone explain it to me? Which one is recommended? Or what are the pro and cons of each one?

Comment: don't forget `o != null`

Comment: @Greg I understand what that means, I listed that I do not understand.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/q/6417902/1260204

Comment: @Igor no it does not.

Comment: It used to be that `is` checked only if the left hand operand was of the same type as the right hand operand, or one of the descendant types, it also ensured the left hand operand was non-null. `is` has changed meaning now, and is also used for pattern matching, and the second expression is the pattern matching way of saying "an object" (as in, not null). So the two expressions you have there does the exact same thing, and will even compile into the exact same code.

Comment: Note that `x is type` will only check that `x` is of the same type as `type`, or one of its descendant types, whereas `x is pattern` is much more powerful when it comes to property matching, such as `shape is Rectangle (100, _)` which matches any `Rectangle` object, for which there is a `Deconstruct` method with two output parameters, first of which will match the value 100.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate so I'd rather avoid doing that until I'm convinced it's not.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen so the first one is using the `is type` checking, and the second one is using pattern matching. and `{}` is just a way of saying this is an object in pattern matching. when it comes to il code they should have the same code. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: it's definitely a duplicate...I'm starting my search now, but I saw and closed essentially this exact same question just in the last month or two. (If only there was an easy way to do a search on closed and/or deleted question by user-casting-vote). I don't have a lot of patience these days to look for dupes, so I might come up empty...but I assure you this question is here with an answer already somewhere, for the person who takes the time to look.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139886/c-sharp-meaning-of-curly-braces-after-the-is-operator and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62212715/what-does-is-syntax-mean-in-c

Comment: _"when it comes to il code they should have the same code"_ -- that's easy enough for you to verify yourself, if it matters to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `o is object` is the original way of checking the type of an instance (available since C# 1.0)
2. `o is {}` uses the pattern matching with [property patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#property-patterns) introduced in C# 8.0

   `{}` denotes an object instance with any (or none) properties, i.e. any object instance.