# C# { } operator

Tags: c#, operators

I cannot find it anywhere. Could you tell me what the expression **{ }** means in c# or give me a link to documentation.

Here is example usage which I have found in my project:

```
Method(IProfileDocument profileDocument)
{
    if(profileDocument.documentId is not { } documentId
    || string.IsNullOrEmpty(documentId))
    { 
       do something...
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/basic-concepts#77-scopes

Comment: The curly braces are a way to indicate scope, and show what is encapsulated within another member.

Comment: You may also see them used in [String Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: You might also see them in an array or list declaration: `new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };`

Comment: Otherwise you may be asking a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139886/meaning-of-curly-braces-after-the-is-operator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Meaning of curly braces after the "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139886/meaning-of-curly-braces-after-the-is-operator)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`{ }` when used with `is` is an empty property pattern.

`{ }` is basically equivalent to `!= null`

Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern

Comment: [This reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern) has the exact `(s is {} x)` pattern seen in the question, and its equivalent statements.  Admittedly, it is one of the weirdest constructs in the language..

Comment: So what is the difference between (s is {} x) and (s is not {} x)?

Comment: not negates the pattern. the difference between `is` and `is not` should be self-explainatory :-)

Answer (score 1):

Property Pattern: A property pattern checks that the input value is not null and recursively matches values extracted by the use of accessible properties or fields.

```
                string s =null;
                if (s is not { } documentId)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    string mj = documentId;
                }
```

Declaration Pattern: The declaration_pattern both tests that an expression is of a given type and casts it to that type if the test succeeds. This may introduce a local variable of the given type named by the given identifier, if the designation is a single_variable_designation.

Here first check profileDocument.documentId is null or not. after that if not null then value asign to new a variable `documentId`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/patterns#property-pattern