# C# is { } keyword usage

Tags: c#

IDE has suggested the following Syntax change

`while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)`

```
           while (sr.ReadLine() is { } line)
            {
                output += line + "\n";
            }
```

Must be a relatively new C# feature, but I am unable to find documentation of this "syntactic sugar" anywhere, involving the `{ }`. I understand what it does but is there any doc anywhere?
I found this but does not seem to be appearing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#list-patterns

Comment: Maybe you can find more when you search `property pattern` [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62139886/meaning-of-curly-braces-after-the-is-operator